# How to apply separate CSS styles to divs in a loop with JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two divs and each div contains two nested divs. If one of the nested divs is taller in height than the other I want certain CSS styles to be applied.

I've managed to get the alerts to work correctly, however I'm a getting a little confused as the CSS styles seem to be applying to both divs.

Any help with finishing this off would be greatly appreciated.

Heres the demo https://jsfiddle.net/Lhn5uxeq/3/

HTML

```
<div class="slideshow" data-id="1">
  <div class="slideshow-info">
    <h1>
     Header
    </h1>
    <p>
     Text
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="slideshow-image">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg"/>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="slideshow" data-id="2">
  <div class="slideshow-info">
    <h1>
     Header
    </h1>
    <p>
     Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text. Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text. Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text. Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text. Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text. Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="slideshow-image">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  calculateHeight();

  $(window).resize(function() {
    calculateHeight();
  });
});

function calculateHeight() {
  $('.slideshow').each(function() {
    $('.slideshow-info', this).each(function() {
      slideInfoHeight = $(this).height();  
    });
    $('.slideshow-image', this).each(function() {
      slideImageHeight = $(this).height();  
    });

    if(slideInfoHeight > slideImageHeight) {
      alert('info is taller than image');
      $('.slideshow-info').css('background-color', 'red');
    } else {
      alert ('info is shorter than image');
      $('.slideshow-info').css('background-color', 'blue');
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I have updated the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Lhn5uxeq/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to apply the css for the div in that specific slideshow only. below code will work. 
https://jsfiddle.net/Lhn5uxeq/5/

```
function calculateHeight() {
  $('.slideshow').each(function() {
    $('.slideshow-info', this).each(function() {
      slideInfoHeight = $(this).height();  
    });
    $('.slideshow-image', this).each(function() {
      slideImageHeight = $(this).height();  
    });

    if(slideInfoHeight > slideImageHeight) {
      alert('info is taller than image');
       $( this ).find( '.slideshow-info' ).css('background-color', 'red');
    } else {
      alert ('info is shorter than image');
      $( this ).find( '.slideshow-info' ).css('background-color', 'blue');
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify that `.slideshow-info` is a child of this. You do that like so `$('.slideshow-info', this)`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  calculateHeight();

  $(window).resize(function() {
    calculateHeight();
  });
});

function calculateHeight() {
  $('.slideshow').each(function() {
    $('.slideshow-info', this).each(function() {
      slideInfoHeight = $(this).height();
    });
    $('.slideshow-image', this).each(function() {
      slideImageHeight = $(this).height();
    });

    if (slideInfoHeight > slideImageHeight) {
      alert('info is taller than image');
      $('.slideshow-info', this).css('background-color', 'red');
    } else {
      alert('info is shorter than image');
      $('.slideshow-info', this).css('background-color', 'blue');
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slideshow" data-id="1">
  <div class="slideshow-info">
    <h1>
      Header
    </h1>
    <p>
      Text
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="slideshow-image">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="slideshow" data-id="1">
  <div class="slideshow-info">
    <h1>
      Header
    </h1>
    <p>
      Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
      Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text. Text
      Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
      Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text.
      Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
      Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
      Text. Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
      Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
      Text Text. Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
      Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
      Text Text Text. Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
      Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
      Text Text Text Text.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="slideshow-image">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What's it doing?